# Add column to table that has converted varchar to date format

Tags: mysql, date, variables, datetime, addition

I have a table with a variable, DATE, in varchar format that looks like this:

DATE

2009-09-23 00:00:00

2004-11-14 00:00:00

etc...

I am trying to add a column named DATE_X that contains the DATE string converted to datetime format.  Can this be accomplished with STR_TO_DATE()?  How do I use this without changing the original column DATE, but rather adding a new column DATE_X?

Thanks!

Comment: Since MySQL effectively treats datetimes as character strings (defaulted to the exact format you describe), with some added datetime functionality and validation, you should really consider just changing the original column. You are just duplicating data otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alter table TableName add column date_x datetime;
update table
set date_x = date;
```

Assigning a string to a `datetime` column will parse it.